# 'Change' event triggers a function only if changes made in a specific sheet and not anywhere in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to call a function when any **new row is inserted** in the 1st sheet of a google spreadsheet. I am using the 'Change' event, however it is triggered when any change is made (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER) in **any of the sheets** in the google spreadsheet.

Comment: You need to check the sheet name and change type.  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var activeSh = ss.getActiveSheet(); var sheetName = activeSh.getSheetName(); if (sheetName !== 'Sheet 1') {continue;} //quit here if the sheet being changed is not sheet one`

Comment: Thanks Sandy. Won't your code be  executed everytime I am editing any cell in any sheet ? Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: There is not a more efficient way.  There is no way to set up the trigger to run only for certain types of changes.